# Facebook publish_action permission review

Tags: facebook

From the official Facebook guideline, app won't get approved for publish_action permission if it **pre-fills** the message user posts on their timeline. However, when I check the BetterMe app (http://bettermeapp.co/), which does exactly the pre-filling message for me, how did it pass the review process?

Comment: I just failed the review for the same reason and the reviewer directed me to Platform Policy 2.3. My application was sending data entered by the user in a previous form together with some text and a link he did not enter. I get that I cannot use the text and link he cannot enter but according to the Policy I can use "content a user manually entered earlier in your app's flow". So that's strange...they should clear up if by "your app" they mean only the Facebook App or your whole app, including your own forms.

Answer (score 0):

Apps cannot pre-fill in general. This is [Facebook Platform Policy](https://developers.facebook.com/policy) 2.3. Apps that are currently pre-filling is using the old Facebook login that will become obsolete in April 2015. For more information, please refer to [Facebook New Login FAQ](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/apps/faq).